# Notation troubles: What is $\hat{C}(I)$ for Ethier and Kurtz 1986?

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation, probability

One finds in Ethier Kurtz 1986 (page 367)

> **1.2. Corollary** Suppose, in addition to the hypotheses of Theorem 1.1, that infinite boundaries of $I$ are natural. Then $\{(f,Gf):f\in\hat{C}(I)\cap\mathscr{D}_0\cap\mathscr{D}_1,Gf\in\hat{C}(I)\}$ generates a Feller semigroup on $\hat{C}(I)$.

I couldn't find a definition on the book (It is a large book, and I found no table of frequently used notations)

What is $\hat{C}(I)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at page 144, $\hat{C}(E)$ is the space of continuous functions on $E$ vanishing at infinity.

Comment: What does it mean to vanish at infinity if $E$ is a general metric space?